# main expects a filename as the first argument ... but I can alternatively provide main the file via a pipe ... how does that work?

Tags: c, unix, bison, flex-lexer

I have a C program with this main() function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    ...
}
```

Notice that it expects, when executing the program, a filename be provided as the first argument, e.g.,

```
main test.dat
```

The program works fine when I run it that way.

Interestingly, the program also works fine when I run it this way:

```
cat test.dat | main
```

That is not providing main() with a filename. It is streaming the content of test.dat to main(). Right? So how does it work?

Further elaboration: The main() function is the main in a Bison parser. I show the main() function below. As I mentioned, the parser works fine whether I invoke it this way:

```
main test.dat
```

or this way:

```
cat test.dat | main
```

Here is the parser's main() function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    yyparse();
    fclose(yyin);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you call the program with no arguments, referencing `argv[1]` is undefined behavior.  I suspect there is more code, and `f` is conditionally assigned ; `f = stdin`

Comment: Edit comment: it is not UB to reference `argv[1]`, but it is to pass NULL as first arg to `fopen`.  Either way, badness ensues.

Comment: The usual technique is to say something like `if(argv < 1) f = stdin; else f = fopen(argv[1], "r"); }`.

Comment: Perhaps on this platform, `fopen(NULL, "r")` returns `stdin`, as some kind of [DWIM](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/D/DWIM.html)?

Comment: What compiler for what target system do you use?

Comment: In @SteveSummitʼs first comment, it should be `if (argc < 1)`.

Comment: Some further elaboration: my main() function is the main of a Bison parser. The parser works fine whether I call it with an explicit filename or via a pipe. It is my understanding that nearly all UNIX programs operate this way - the program may be invoked explicitly with filenames or via a pipe. Right? So how do UNIX programs do it?

Comment: @the busybee I am using gcc

Comment: So on your system with the version of GCC you use, `fopen(NULL, "r")` returns a valid `FILE*`? Hm, strange, I can't believe. Would you mind to extend your source excerpt until and including the first function that reads from `f`? And you could add some debug output, for example printing `argv[1]` and `f`.

Comment: @the busybee I added the entire main() function to my question. See above.

Comment: Now you need to add the specific version of Bison to your question, optimally with a link to its source code or documentation. Most probably `yyparse()` checks the value of `yyin` and (re)sets it to `stdin` if it is `NULL`.

Comment: @thebusybee: (f)lex, not yacc/bison. The parser does not interact with stdio at all; that's left to the lexical scanner. The behaviour is documented, also in Posix, and has been like that since the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that you don't verify that `fopen` worked. *Every* call to `fopen()` should be followed by a check that the return value was not NULL. Otherwise, you will never notice that a user misspelled a filename, for example.

Normally, trying to use NULL `FILE*` arguments to stdio functions is Undefined Behaviour, which typically results in a segfault. That doesn't happen with `yyin` because the NULL is never passed through to stdio; the flex scanner notices that `yyin` is NULL and converts it to `stdin`. It does that because `stdin` is the default input source (as per the Posix standard). Similarly, a NULL `yyout` is treated as though it were `stdout`.

It's probably OK to rely on this behaviour from Flex. But it should only be used deliberately, not accidentally.

If your application is invoked with no command-line arguments, then `argc` will be 1, `argv[0]` will be the name used to invoke the program, and `argv[1]` will be NULL. (Technically, `argc` could be 0, with even worse consequences, but that's unlikely in practice.) You then pass that `NULL` to `fopen`, which is Undefined Behaviour (that is to say, a grievous error). The implementation of `fopen` in your standard library returns an error indication rather than segfaulting [Note 1], but as noted above you don't check for this error return. So the compounding of errors happens to result in `yyin` being NULL, and Flex reading from `stdin`.

You should always check for validity of user input. Always. Without exception. And you should report errors, or deal with them. There are no excuses. Not checking is dangerous, and at best wastes a lot of time; yours and that of whoever you enlist to help you.

Correct code might look like this:

```c
    if (argc > 1) {
        yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (yyin == NULL) {
            fprintf("Could not open file '%s': %s\n",
                     argv[1], strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else {
        /* argc <= 1, so there was no command line argument.
         * Read from stdin.
         */
        yyin = stdin;
    }
```

---

#### Notes

1. Most stdio libraries on Unix-like systems implement `fopen` by first calling the Posix-defined `open` function. The filename is simply passed through, so it's not examined at all. `open` is usually a system call, so it's executed in kernel mode; that requires it to copy the filename from user memory to kernel memory, which in turn requires it to first validate the address. So on Unix, passing an invalid string pointer to `fopen` is likely to produced some kind of error indication. This is not required by any standard, and there is no specification of the `errno` code to use. It might not be the case on non-Posix platforms, where it's quite possible that `fopen` needs to transform the filepath in some way prior to passing it to the native file system. (For example, it might need to translate `/` directory separators to something else.) On such systems, it is quite likely that the filename argument will not be checked for validity, and the `fopen` library function will segfault (or equivalent) when it tries to use an invalid filename pointer.

   On most common Unix stdio library implementations, `fopen` **will** segfault if the `mode` argument is specified as `NULL`. Like all library functions, `fopen` is under no obligation to cope with `NULL` pointer arguments; the C standard insists that it is undefined behaviour to pass `NULL` as a pointer argument to any library function unless that library function is explicitly documented as accepting `NULL` for that argument. (See, for example, `free`, `realloc`, and `strtok` for library functions which explicitly allow `NULL`.) `fopen` is not such a function, so you shouldn't pass `NULL` as any argument, and you certainly shouldn't assume that the result will just be an error return.

Comment: @steve: thanks for the fixes. I was getting there. :-)

Comment: It was penance for the typo in the comment of mine on the original question, that I now can't fix. :-)

Comment: This is almost right about how the program as given manages to successfully execute.  argv[1] will indeed be NULL, fopen on a NULL path will return NULL per the man page.  That means yyin is NULL.  yyparse() will call yylex(), which contains a default implementationj of file input.  That default scanner function will reset yyin to stdin if yyin is NULL.  None of this behavior is undefined per se, but it's still bad practice because it depends on behavior buried way down in the lexer.

Comment: @thomas: What manpage says that `fopen(NULL,...)` returns NULL? Not the Linux manpage afaics, and the C standard says it must be a string; `NULL` is not a string. As to the style question, you're entitled to your opinion of course, but lots of parsers never touch `yyin`, leaving it as the default value -- NULL --, which results in taking input from stdin. I personally see no reason to castigate this as "bad practice", but in any event you can see that my code doesn't do that (mostly to avoid UB on `fclose(yyin)`).

Comment: @rici:  Read the part under "Return Value" specifying that on an unsuccessful call NULL is returned.  Implmentations of the C standard library will tend to read this as "I don't have permission to crash on a NULL pointer" and will protect themselves according, regarding a NULL path parameter as a "failed call" situation.  There's some room for interpretation, sure, but the text of the "Return Value" section of the man page is probably pretty broadly construed thus.

Comment: @rici:  Also, I said "bad practice" because the consequences of executing the code on bad values aren't clear from the code as given (not yours in your answer, the original in the question).  Depending on what may be implementation-dependent behavior (someone else might interpret the "Return Value" part of the man page slightly differently) and on  behavior of the lexer on a NULL yyin value the resolution of which is at least two call stack layers deeper than the code under question above doesn't seem like "good" practice to me.  YOMV.